# How to modify json file and foreach loop structure

Tags: json, foreach, yii

i have Yii code as-

```
public function actionpublishPollResult()
    {
        $model=new Polloption();
        $json='{"pollId":2}';    
        $obj=json_decode($json);
        $model->pollId=$obj->pollId;
        $options=Polloption::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pollId'=>$model->pollId));
        $total=0;

        foreach ($options as $option)
        {

            echo "option id :-".$option->optionId."<br>";
            $vote=new Pollvote();
            echo "Number of votes to option :".$option->optionId." "."is=".count($option->pollvotes)."</br>";
            $total=$total+count($option->pollvotes);
            $data[] =count($option->pollvotes);
        }
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Total number of votes obtained=".$total;
        foreach ($data as $votepercentage)
        {
            $percentageResult[]=$votepercentage/$total*100;
        }

        echo "</br>";
        echo CJSON::encode(array('options'=>$options,'percentagevotes'=>$percentageResult));

    }
```

So it is giving me output as

{"options":[{"optionId"=>1,"option"=>"abc"},{"optionId"=>2,"option"=>"xyz"}],{"percentagevotes":[25,75]}}

But i want to add this percentagevotes field in options array only. So what changes i need to make in above foreach structure. Because $total will obtain only after whole loop of options is executed.. So how to calculate and add percentagevotes field in foreach of options only. Please guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your second `foreach` loop as

```
$toJson=array();
foreach ($data as $i=>$votepercentage)
        {
            $tmp=array();
            $tmp['optionId']=$option[$i]->optionId;
            $tmp['option']=$option[$i]->option;
            $tmp['percentageVote']=$votepercentage/$total*100;
            $toJson[]=$tmp;

        }
```

then

```
  echo CJSON::encode(array('options'=>$toJson));
```

Comment: Ya sir...i have made changes as above. But its not displaying percentage field in options array.